# How to implement tear off tabs like AvalonDock

Tags: c#, wpf, mdi

Certain MDI applications such as Visual Studio and SharpDevelop (the latter using [AvalonDock](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/)) allow you to tear tabs out of the parent window by dragging, and later you can drag them back into position.

How can one go about implementing such functionality using C# and WPF?

Comment: `OnDrag[...etc]` handlers.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742859%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Why not just use AvalonDock?  The free version is on Codeplex.

Comment: I know, but I still want to understand the technology. Also, I found AvalonDock 2.0 pretty lacking in terms of documentation... the docs are for some previous version and no longer apply.

Comment: Been there, done that :)  But once you settle on a consistent tear-off interface from their library, the amount of documentation needed is reduced dramatically.